# Wordpress Query_posts returning only 6 posts. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am a plugin developer and I'm using the following function to query particular posts in wordpress in my plugin. The problem is that even when  `$this->params['num']` is set to something like 12, the query is only returning 6 posts. My Plugin can be found [HERE](http://www.evilgenius.anshulsharma.in/cgview/).
It is working fine for me and in most cases. But i have got 2 odd support queries from users that in their case it did not work. Is it because of an older wordpress version or because of some conflict with their theme?
[Here](http://animeshin.cba.pl/?page_id=12) is one conflicting page (he uses WP 3.0.5)

```
private function lcp_set_categories(){
    if($this->params['name'] != '' && $this->params['id'] == '0'){
        $this->cgid = $this->get_category_id_by_name($this->params['name']);
    }else{
        $this->cgid = $this->params['id'];
    }

    $lcp_category = 'cat=' . $this->cgid;

    //Build the query for get_posts()
    $cgquery = 'cat=' . $this->cgid .
                            '&posts_per_page=' . $this->params['num'] .
                            '&orderby=' . $this->params['orderby'] .
                            '&order=' . $this->params['order'] .
                            '&exclude=' . $this->params['excludeposts'] .
                            '&tag=' . $this->params['tags'] .
                            '&offset=' . $this->params['offset'].
                            '&meta_key=' . $this->params['customfield'].
                            '&meta_value=' . $this->params['customfieldvalue'];

    $this->cgposts = get_posts($cgquery);

}
```

Comment: UPDATE: MODIFIED the code, still having problem with some themes, like AGGREGATE theme. I believe its conflicting with some other posts loop. now i am using
`$tmp_query = new WP_Query;`
From my understanding i thought that "query" function calls the get_posts function which does NOT use the global $wp_query object. so it should not conflict with the themes loop
  `$this->cgposts = $tmp_query->query($cgquery);`

Comment: You are right. If you are creating a new WP_Query object then it shouldn't conflict with other queries in your theme. Try debugging your plugin/theme with Xdebug to find your conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling the function with the wrong parameters. Refer here http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-query_posts-and-get_posts for a quick explanation, and refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: It's as if you're trying to do: `$tmp_query = new WP_Query;
    $tmp_result = $tmp_query->query($cgquery);` instead.

Comment: I have modified my code, see above comment. Still not working with some themes like aggregate theme.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same problem. After a little bit of searching, I finally found this solution:

```
query_posts("showposts=-1");
```

By adding the parameter which set `show posts` to `-1`, I managed to get all posts. Hope this is helpful.